# Spring Boot: How to specify nameID policy for SAML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using Spring Boot v2.3.3.

I am trying to add SSO support to my application by using the saml support added to spring in v5.2: (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#saml2)

I am fairly new to Spring and SAML, and while that reference page mentions that the current feature set "Supports encrypted NameId elements", I am not sure how to configure the application to add a name ID format, or how to send the name ID to the Identity Provider.

I replicated the Spring Boot sample application here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.3.x/samples/boot/saml2login), but my IDP says they need a nameID as well.

Any help in understanding what I need to add will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your are using code-based configuration you could use

```
  @Bean
  public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
    WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
    // do not enable IdP-Proxy support
    webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
    webSSOProfileOptions.setNameID(NameIDType.TRANSIENT);
    return webSSOProfileOptions;
  }
```

However normally the IdP defines it supported NameID formats in the IdP meta data file Spring Security SAML would use the first NameID format specified. You could reorder this.

Comment: Thank you! I WAS using properties to let Spring Boot create my bean for me, but just last night I switched to a code-based config.
I didn't know Spring uses the first NameID specified. I will try it out without the bean, and if it doesn't work, I will try with it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi! So, I tried this bit of code and I realized it is using WebSSOProfileOptions from the Spring SAML extension. I am using the new SAML library from Spring Security Core. :(